# Стоит ли делать валидацию данных в админ-панели?

Tags: валидация, админка

Валидация на фронте - это понятно, для самоконтроля. А валидация на сервере нужна? И второй вопрос, как лучше сделать сохранение данных при редактировании, скажем, товара. По кнопке сохранить, или при изменении полей? PHP+Jquery(ajax)

Comment: «А валидация на сервере нужна?» — конечно же нужна, ведь валидацию на фронте можно обойти и злоумышленник, случайно получивший доступ к админ-панели, без валидации на сервере сможет натворить больше бед чем в случае если бы валидация была

Comment: «По кнопке сохранить, или при изменении полей» — а это вы уже сами решаете, как вам удобнее

Comment: я бы кроме валидации на сервере еще бы и тестами обложил.